# How to get to a laravel route using jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, routes

I am trying to put to a method in a controller using ajax but I keep getting a 404 not found.

My JS:

```
var dataroomForm = $('#dataroomForm');
var dataroomId = $('#dataroomId').val();
var saveButton = $('.saveDataroom');

saveButton.click(function(e) {
    var dataroomData = dataroomForm.serialize();
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(dataroomData);

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    $.ajax({

        url: '/dataroom/' + dataroomId,
        type: 'PUT',
        data: {
            'dataroom': dataroomData
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (request, error) {
            alert("Request: " + JSON.stringify(request));
        }
    });

});
```

The route I am trying to trigger:

```
Route::put('dataroom/{dataroom}', ['as' => 'update', 'uses' => 'DataroomController@update']);
```

And update method (not really relevant I think but posting for complete view)

```
public function update(DataroomRequest $request, $id, MailService $mailService)
{
    $dataroom = Dataroom::withoutGlobalScope(ActiveScope::class)->find($id);
    if (is_null($dataroom)) {
        \Flash::error('Dataroom niet gevonden!');
        return redirect(route('admin.dataroom.index'));
    }

    $dataroom->fill($request->all());
    $dataroom->save();

    $dataroom->handleUploader($request, 'image');

    if ($request->has('send_update')) {
        $changes = $request->input('changes');

        foreach ($dataroom->accounts as $account) {
            $mailService->sendUpdate($account, $dataroom, $changes);
        }

        if (empty($changes)) {
            $changes = 'Dataroom gewijzigd';
        }

        $dataroom->log($changes);
    }

    \Flash::success('De wijzigingen voor <strong>' . $dataroom->title . '</strong> zijn opgeslagen');

    return redirect()->route('admin.dataroom.index');
}
```

In my network tab I get:

```
Request URL: http://website.nl.test/dataroom/26
Request Method: PUT
Status Code: 404 Not Found
```

And as response : `exception: "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException"`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `dd()` the request to check if the request enters the mehtod or not and check if the record with id 26 exists.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issues in your code try using the command in your terminal `php artisan optimize:clear` in root folder this will flush/remove the application cache, route cache, and config cache altogether.